# (.NET) What classes implement Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.TimeZone

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, ms-office

I'm having trouble finding any classes that implement Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.TimeZone. Do any such classes exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need TimeZoneClass.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.timezoneclass.aspx

Comment: Looks like you're right, but sadly this class doesn't appear to have a useful constructor. I wonder if there is a factory that works with it.